# Function returns different values when debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vtk

I have the following piece of code;

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points = doc->m_.points;
    for(int i =0; i<points->GetNumberOfPoints();i++){
        double point[3];
        points->GetPoint(i,point);
    }
```

I afterwards write these point values into a file. When I run the program normally (in debug configuration) and check the file, between i =921 to i =950, all node values are like the following;

```
    921 -0.86404 -1.56526e+020 1.45676 
    922 -3.22686e-024 1.65049 -1.84038e+018 
    923 -0.688541 -1.17037e+031 1.45647 
    924 3.87651e-010 1.6554 1.05914e-009 
    925 0.813721 8.37409e-010 1.45736 
    926 8.80064e+037 1.6603 9.43973e-033
```

But when I debug the piece of code (in debug configuration)  I can see that the GetPoint() returns the following values which are correctly written into the file;

```
    921 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 
    922 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 
    923 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 
    924 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 
    925 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 
    926 -0.00132704 -0.00132704 -0.00132704
```

How can this be? The getPoint() is an internal vtk function.

Comment: This could be because when between i=921 and i=950, the GetPoint function somehow failed to set the values in the array points. In this case, the array points are full of garbage values in the stack.

Comment: what should the correct values look like? the values in the first case look garbage, in the second case they are all the same and it seems suspect... is doc->_m being modified by something else in your program? maybe it was not updated yet at the moment of reading. Or maybe the problem is in writing the file (you don't show the code that handles "point", as it is it looks that you are just forgetting about it). If you can save doc->_m in vtk format, then you can open the resulting file in a text editor and check the values there